# VBA: Sub Workbook_BeforeClose for deleting the data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm deleting the data in my speadsheet befor close it like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("GET_NOM_CONTRACTANT_C4") = ""
Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("C6") = ""
Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("GET_EFFET_SOUSCRIPTION_C7") = ""
```

....

But I would like to do that after the message :

[image]

I mean that I would like to make a choice : save as or not, and close the speardsheet with the data.

I don't know how to improve the code.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Taking Control Over Closing a Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim msg As Variant
    msg = MsgBox("Do you wanna save with clearing the ranges?", _
        vbInformation + vbYesNoCancel, "Save Workbook")
    Select Case msg
    Case vbYes ' Range is 'emptied' and the workbook is saved and closed.
        With Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial")
            .Range("GET_NOM_CONTRACTANT_C4") = ""
            .Range("C6") = ""
            .Range("GET_EFFET_SOUSCRIPTION_C7") = ""
        End With
        Me.Save
    Case vbNo
        If Not Me.Saved Then
            ' Either, if you don't wanna save the changes before closing...
            'Me.Saved = True
            ' ..., or if you wanna save as is before closing:
            Me.Save
        End If
    Case vbCancel ' You've changed your mind: nothing will happen.
        Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. I have a question: If I use this code in "File_work1" and save AS this file as "File_work2"  and after choose YES on "Do you wanna save with clearing the ranges?" the "File_work2" is empty and "File_work1" doesn't.                                                                                                                           I'm wondering how to deactivate this code in copied file.

Comment: If I correctly understood, you could put the code in an `If` clause: `If Me.Name = "File_work1" Then : ...: End If`, if you just want to run it in this particular workbook.

Answer (score 0):

BeforeClose is the last accessible event, but not the last.

You may want to store the Saved property of the workbook and then reset it after your routine.

Something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   
   dim wasSaved as Boolean

   wasSaved=ThisWorkbook.Saved
   ' do your stuff
   ThisWorkbook.Saved=wasSaved

end sub
```

In this way, Excel will ask for saving only if the workbook wasn't saved.